# what is the relation between these char str[10], char *str and char *str[10] in C?

Tags: arrays, c, initialization, declaration, string-literals

Can I consider *str[10] as two dimensional array ?
If I declare char *str[10]={"ONE","TWO","THREE"} how we can access single character ?

Comment: Your title doesn't seem to match what you're asking in the question.

Answer (score 1):

This record

```
char str[10];
```

is a declaration of an array with 10 elements of the type `char`, For example you can initialize the array like

```
char str[10] = "ONE";
```

This initialization is equivalent to

```
char str[10] = { 'O', 'N', 'E', '\0' };
```

all elements of the array that are not explicitly initialized are zero-initialized.

And you may change elements of the array like

```
str[0] = 'o';
```

or

```
strcpy( str, "TWO" );
```

This record

```
char *str;
```

declares a pointer to an object of the type `char`. You can initialize it for example like

```
char *str = "ONE";
```

In this case the pointer will be initialize by the address of the first character of the string literal.

This record

```
char * str[10];
```

is a declaration of an array of 10 elements that has the pointer type `char *`.

You can initialize it as for example

```
char * str[10] = { "ONE", "TWO", "THREE" };
```

In this case the first three elements of the array will be initialized by addresses of first characters of the string literals specified explicitly. All other elements will be initialized as null pointers.

You may not change the string literals pointed to by elements of the array. Any attempt to change a string literal results in undefined behavior.

To access elements of the string literals using the array you can use for example two subscript operator. For example

```
for ( sisze_t i = 0; str[0][i] != '\0'; ++i )
{
    putchar( str[0][i] );
}
putchar( '\n' );
```

If you want to change strings then you need to declare for example a two dimensional array like

```
char str[][10] = { "ONE", "TWO", "THREE" };
```

In this case you can change elements of the array that are in turn one-dimensional arrays as for example

```
str[0][0] = 'o';
```

or

```
strcpy( str[0], "FOUR" );
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes: `char* str[10];` would create an array of 10 pointers to chars.

To access a single character, we can access it like a 2 dimensional array; i.e.:

```cpp
char* str[10]={"ONE","TWO","THREE"};
char first = str[0][0];
```

Answer (score 0):

> Can I consider *str[10] as two dimensional array ?

It's unclear what you mean.  `*str[10]` is not a valid type name, and the context is a bit lacking to determine how else to interpret it.

If you mean it as an *expression* referencing the subsequent definition then no, its type is `char`, but evaluating it produces undefined behavior.

If you are asking about the type of the object identified by `str`, referencing the subsequent definition, then again no.  In this case it is a one-dimensional array of pointers to `char`.

> If I declare char *str[10]={"ONE","TWO","THREE"} how we can access single character ?

You can access one of the pointers by indexing `str`, among other other ways.  For example, `str[1]`.  You can access one of the characters in the string into which that pointer points by using the indexing operator again, among other ways.  For example, `str[1][0]`.  That you are then using a double index does not make `str` a 2D array.  The memory layout is quite different than if you declared, say, `char str[3][10];`.